# ActiveRecord association not being set in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, associations, factory-bot

I’m sure this is a “duh" newbie-type question, but I’ve been at it for days and cannot figure out why my code isn’t setting a relationship in the database correctly. I have a simple belongs_to relationship between two models.

```
class Pod < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instigator, :class_name => “User"

  attr_accessor :instigator, :instigator_id, :title

  validates_presence_of :instigator, :title
  validates_associated :instigator
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :instigated_pods, inverse_of: :instigator, :class_name => "Pod", as: "instigator"
end
```

Then I want to test them with rspec and Factory Girl using (what I think) are, again, pretty simple factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :pod do
    title           "Test pod"
    instigator
  end

  factory :user, aliases: [:instigator] do
    username
  end

end
```

With this setup, most tests pass, but my PodsController update test kept failing, and I finally found a test that shows why.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Pod, type: :model do
  it "saves the relationship to the database" do
    pod = FactoryGirl.create(:pod)
    expect(pod.save).to be_truthy
    expect(pod.reload.instigator).to_not be_nil          # passes - cached?

    pod_from_database = Pod.find(pod.id)
    expect(pod_from_database.instigator).to_not be_nil   # <- fails
  end
end
```

It seems that something is preventing the pod.instigator_id from being set in the database, so the relationship isn’t persisting. And I have no clue why!!!

I tried setting `validates_presence_of :instigator_id`, but that makes most of the standard rspec tests fail, and I saw this from [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html):

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to test
>   whether the associated object itself is present, and not the foreign key used
>   to map the association.
>
> ```
> class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
>   belongs_to :order
>   validates :order, presence: true
> end
> ```
>
> In order to validate associated records whose presence is required, you must
>   specify the `:inverse_of` option for the association:
>
> ```
> class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :order
> end
> ```

Any help straightening this out would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

While I’m not altogether clear why, it appears that removing the line

```
attr_accessor :instigator, :instigator_id, :title
```

solves the problem. It appears to be blocking writing these attributes. Any indicator why would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`attr_accessor` is a ruby method that makes a getter and a setter(make them able to be read and to be written), this is not Database fields which called `attr_accessible` in Rails 3.

what you did is declare an ruby methods this is why it doesn't worked.

read more here:

http://rubyinrails.com/2014/03/17/what-is-attr_accessor-in-rails/